# Binary Search Tree Implementation (practice)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree

Note: I do know that `Python` libraries provide `Binary Search Tree`. This implementation has been done to practice python, and `data structures and Algorithms`.

This is a implemented `Binary Search Tree`, feel free to make any suggestions about `syntax`, `logic`, or simply anything that you think i should become aware of.

Methods:

```
tree_insert(i) - handles inserting values, it will refuse to accept a key that already exist.

walk_tree(type) - walks the tree from root, default is in-order
inorder_tree_walk(node)
preorder_tree_walk(node)
postorder_tree_walk(node)


Search_tree_from_root(search_type, key) - looks for key from root based on type given
tree_min() - finds max key
tree_max() - finds min key
tree_search_recursive(key) - search for key from root recursively
tree_search_iterative(key) - search for key from root iteratively

tree_successor(key)- finds successor of the key
tree_predecessor(key)- finds predecessor of the key

tree_delete(i) - handles deleting a key. Delete method, uses the transplant method to move branches around
transplant(second,first)
tree_burn() - deletes everything in tree
```

How to use:

```
from binarySearchTree import BTree


def main():
print("_____INSERT____")
my_tree = BTree()
my_list = [12, 5, 18, 2, 9, 15, 19, 17, 13]
for i in my_list:
    my_tree.tree_insert(i)
print("INSERT DONE")

print("______________TREE_INSET_TRY_Duplicate______________________")
my_tree.tree_insert(12)

print("____________GET_ROOT_KEY_____________________")
print(my_tree.get_root())
print("______________TREE_WALK______________________")
my_tree.walk_tree(3)
my_tree.walk_tree(2)
my_tree.walk_tree()

print("__________TREE_SEARCH_FROM_ROOT_______________")
my_tree.search_tree_from_root(0, 15)
my_tree.search_tree_from_root(1, 19)
my_tree.search_tree_from_root(2)
my_tree.search_tree_from_root(3)

print("_____KEY_SUCCESSOR____")
my_tree.tree_successor(12)

print("_____KEY_PREDECESSOR____")
my_tree.tree_predecessor(5)

print("______________TREE_Delete______________________")
my_tree.tree_delete(100)

print("______________TREE_Delete______________________")
my_tree.tree_delete(15)

print("______________TREE_WALK______________________")
my_tree.walk_tree()

print("______________TREE_BURN______________________")
my_tree.burn_tree()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

OutPUT:

```
_____INSERT____
INSERT DONE
______________TREE_INSET_TRY_Duplicate______________________
12  already Exist, can not add
____________GET_ROOT_KEY_____________________
12
______________TREE_WALK______________________
_____TREE_WALK_POSTORDER____
2
9
5
13
17
15
19
18
12
_____TREE_WALK_PREORDER____
12
5
2
9
18
15
13
17
19
_____TREE_WALK_INORDER____
2
5
9
12
13
15
17
18
19
__________TREE_SEARCH_FROM_ROOT_______________
_____ITERATIVE_TREE_SEARCH____
15
_____RECURSIVE_TREE_SEARCH____
19
_____TREE_MAX____
19
_____TREE_MIN____
2
_____KEY_SUCCESSOR____
13
_____KEY_PREDECESSOR____
2
______________TREE_Delete______________________
search Done
Not Found
______________TREE_Delete______________________
search Done
Delete Done
______________TREE_WALK______________________
_____TREE_WALK_INORDER____
2
5
9
12
13
17
18
19
______________TREE_BURN______________________
19
search Done
Delete Done
18
search Done
Delete Done
17
search Done
Delete Done
13
search Done
Delete Done
12
search Done
Delete Done
9
search Done
Delete Done
5
search Done
Delete Done
2
search Done
Delete Done

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Classes:

```
# simple node class
class TreeNode:
    # constructor
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.value = data
        self.right_child = None
        self.left_child = None
        # only used in delete and transplant can also use predecessor and SUCCESSOR instead
        self.prev_node = None

# binary search tree class
class BTree:
    # constructor
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = TreeNode(None)
        self.count = 0

    # insert method
    def tree_insert(self, value):
        # make new node
        new_node = TreeNode(value)
        # pointer that walks the tree to find the spot
        tracer = self.root
        # follow the pointer that is walking the tree to find a spot, always one step behind
        tracer_trailer = None
        while tracer is not None:
            tracer_trailer = tracer
            if tracer.value is None:
                break
            else:
                if new_node.value < tracer.value:
                    tracer = tracer.left_child
                elif new_node.value == tracer.value:
                    print(value, " already Exist, can not add")
                    break
                else:
                    tracer = tracer.right_child
                self.count += 1
        # Set Pointers that cause key to be inserted
        if tracer_trailer.value is None:
            self.root = new_node
        elif new_node.value == tracer_trailer.value:
            return False
        elif new_node.value < tracer_trailer.value:
            new_node.prev_node = tracer_trailer
            tracer_trailer.left_child = new_node
        else:
            new_node.prev_node = tracer_trailer
            tracer_trailer.right_child = new_node

# delete method, uses the transplant method to move branches around
    def tree_delete(self, key):
        root = self.root
        if root is not None:
            node = self.tree_search_iterative(root, key)
            print("search Done")
            if node is not None:
                # removing node has no left child
                if node.left_child is None:
                    self.transplant(node, node.right_child)
                # removing node has no right child
                elif node.right_child is None:
                    self.transplant(node, node.left_child)
                # removing node has two children
                else:
                    # find successor in that side
                    temp = self.tree_min(node.right_child)
                    if temp.prev_node != node:
                        self.transplant(temp, temp.right_child)
                        temp.right_child = node.right_child
                        temp.right_child.prev_node = temp

                    self.transplant(node, temp)
                    temp.left_child = node.left_child
                    temp.left_child.prev_node = temp
                print("Delete Done")
                self.count -= 1
            else:
                print("Not Found")

    # used in delete; handles moving nodes and transplanting nodes
    def transplant(self, first_node, second_node):
        if first_node.prev_node is None:
            self.root = second_node
        elif first_node == first_node.prev_node.left_child:
            first_node.prev_node.left_child = second_node
        else:
            first_node.prev_node.right_child = second_node
        if second_node is not None:
            second_node.prev_node = first_node.prev_node


# --------in-order, pre-order, post-order tree walks-------------
    def inorder_tree_walk(self, node):
        if node is not None:
            self.inorder_tree_walk(node.left_child)
            print(node.value)
            self.inorder_tree_walk(node.right_child)

    def preorder_tree_walk(self, node):
        if node is not None:
            print(node.value)
            self.preorder_tree_walk(node.left_child)
            self.preorder_tree_walk(node.right_child)

    def postorder_tree_walk(self, node):
        if node is not None:
            self.postorder_tree_walk(node.left_child)
            self.postorder_tree_walk(node.right_child)
            print(node.value)

    # accessor to three different tree walks, will do it from root, default is in-order
    def walk_tree(self, walk_type=None):
        root = self.root
        if walk_type == 3:
            print("_____TREE_WALK_POSTORDER____")
            self.postorder_tree_walk(root)
        elif walk_type == 2:
            print("_____TREE_WALK_PREORDER____")
            self.preorder_tree_walk(root)
        else:
            print("_____TREE_WALK_INORDER____")
            self.inorder_tree_walk(root)

# --------recursive, iterative, max, min, search methods-------------
    def tree_search_recursive(self, node, key):
        if node is not None:
            if node is not None:
                if key == node.value:
                    return key
                if key < node.value:
                    return self.tree_search_recursive(node.left_child, key)
                else:
                    return self.tree_search_recursive(node.right_child, key)
        else:
            print("NOT FOUND")

    def tree_search_iterative(self, node, key):
        if key is not None:
            while True:
                if node is None:
                    return None
                if key == node.value:
                    break
                if key < node.value:
                    node = node.left_child
                else:
                    node = node.right_child
            return node
        else:
            print("NOT FOUND")

    def tree_max(self, node):
        if node is not None:
            while node.right_child is not None:
                node = node.right_child
            return node
        else:
            print("Tree is empty")

    def tree_min(self, node):
        if node is not None:
            while node.left_child is not None:
                node = node.left_child
            return node
        else:
            print("Tree is empty")

    # search for a key using iterative, recursive, or search for max and min from root, default is Iterative
    def search_tree_from_root(self, search_type=None, key=None):
        root = self.root
        if root is not None:
            if search_type == 3:
                print("_____TREE_MIN____")
                found_node = self.tree_min(root)
                if found_node is not None:
                    print(found_node.value)
                else:
                    print("Not Found")

            elif search_type == 2:
                print("_____TREE_MAX____")
                found_node = self.tree_max(root)
                if found_node is not None:
                    print(found_node.value)
                else:
                    print("Not Found")
            elif search_type == 1:
                print("_____RECURSIVE_TREE_SEARCH____")
                found_node = self.tree_search_recursive(root, key)
                if found_node is not None:
                    print(found_node)
                else:
                    print("Not Found")
            elif search_type == 0:
                print("_____ITERATIVE_TREE_SEARCH____")
                found_node = self.tree_search_iterative(root, key)
                if found_node is not None:
                    print(found_node.value)
                else:
                    print("Not Found")
        else:
            print("Tree is Empty")

# successor and predecessor methods
    def tree_successor(self, key):
        root = self.root
        if root is not None:
            node = self.tree_search_iterative(root, key)

            if node.right_child is not None:
                found_node = self.tree_min(node.right_child)
                if found_node is not None:
                    print(found_node.value)
                return found_node

            prev = node.prev_node

            while prev is not None and node == node.right_child:
                node = prev
                prev = prev.prev_node

            if prev is not None:
                print(prev.value)

            return prev

        else:
            print("Tree is empty")

    def tree_predecessor(self, key):
        root = self.root
        if root is not None:
            node = self.tree_search_iterative(root, key)

            if node.left_child is not None:
                found_node = self.tree_max(node.left_child)
                if found_node is not None:
                    print(found_node.value)
                return found_node

            prev = node.prev_node

            while prev is not None and node == node.left_child:
                node = prev
                prev = prev.prev_node

            if prev is not None:
                print(prev.value)

            return prev
        else:
            print("Tree is empty")

    def get_root(self):
        return self.root.value

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.walk_tree()

    def __len__(self):
        return self.count

    def burn_tree(self):
        while self.root is not None:
            highest_num = self.tree_max(self.root)
            print(highest_num.value)
            self.tree_delete(highest_num.value)
            self.count -= 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's some general critique.

1. Don't call it a `BTree` -- that's a [related but significantly different data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-Tree). Call it a `MyBinaryTree`.
2. It's not necessary for the methods to all have the word "tree" in them. That just adds wordiness and doesn't help with code readability.
3. Don't use `print` statements to signal errors. What if your code is used in a situation without a console, such as a batch/background process or GUI? Python has [a very good exception mechanism](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Exceptions); use it.
4. Don't use `print` statements for logging progress or debug info; use [the built-in logging library](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial).
5. Also, the "already exists" error should exit the function, not break. Throwing an exception already takes care of that.
6. Your `preorder_tree_walk` and `postorder_tree_walk` don't work as intended, as is evident from their output. Look carefully at how you recurse.
7. Extra comma here `def search_tree_from_root(self, search_type=None, key=None,):`
8. Don't use magic numbers to implement an enumeration. Instead use a real enumeration. You'll have to move up to Python 3.4 or later -- which you should do anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i will correct the mistakes. for some reason i call in order inside both post-order and pre-order, i fixed thoes.

Answer (score 4):

Python 3.x provides `collections.abc` which includes Abstract Base Classes useful for defining classes that will emulate certain Python container behavior.

As you have written it, your tree class appears to behave like a `MutableSet` more than anything else - you can insert and remove items, check for membership, and iterate over all the items.

I suggest you implement the `MutableSet` interface. You might also try `Reversible`, and you can certainly include some other iterator types (pre-order, post-order) as specially-named methods.